# windows file system ,not able to delete the directory structure

Tags: windows, file, system

I was running a Tibco process in Windows. It recursively created a directory structure like shown below:

```
E:\Aman\TIBPRO~1\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\PROJEC~1\Archives\ProjectData\Archives
```

Now I am not able to delete it. Can somebody help me delete this.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Create a drive using a folder of this path, so that your path will become short in new drive. Then delete the folder from new drive, it will be deleted from actual folder also.

To create a drive using folder

1. Go to command prompt
2. Go to directory which you want to delete using `cd` command
3. Type `subst J: "Path of the folder you want to delete"`  It will create new drive
4. New drive will be created.
5. Go to new drive and delete files
6. Go back to your command window and type `subst /d J:` to delete the newly created drive.

Comment: Not working : i 'm getting similar error even with this method.

Comment: @aman your question is off topic , as it is not related to programming :D

Comment: Edited 3rd step.